# Why this function is in this Sobolev space?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset R^n  (n \geq 2)$ a bounded domain with smooth boundary. Let $\phi \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega) \ (2 \leq p < \infty)$ with $\phi^{+}$ different from the null function. Let $j_0 \in N$ the smallest natural number such that $j_0 \geq  \| \phi\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}.$  Let $ u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $u - \varphi \in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega).$

I am reading a paper and the paper says that $ (|u| - j)^{+} \in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$ for $ j \in N$ with $j > j_0$. I have no idea of how prove this. Someone could help me ?

Thanks you for your attention.

Comment: You may check Stampacchia Theorem. From it follows that $|u-\varphi|,(u-\varphi)^+, (u-\varphi)^-\in W_0^{1,p}$. Also if $a\leq 0\leq b$ then $(u-\varphi-b)^+\in W_0^{1,p}$ and $(u-\varphi -a)^-\in W_0^{1,p}$

Comment: I can not see it right now, can you write some short proof ?

Comment: for a moment I thought that I had the proof, but when I started to write, I found a problem in my reasoning

Comment: Well, this happens :) Still, if you find a proof, please tell it here.

Comment: Yes =). Ok =) , Thanks for your attention

Comment: I found a proof =)

Comment: I meant to share the proof :)

Comment: After I wrote my commentary "I found a proof =)" , I started to write the proof =)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help someone one day. Since I saw this argument in a paper, maybe it is important.

Since $u - \varphi \in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$,  we have

$|u - \varphi| \in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega).$

Note that $||u(x)| - |\varphi (x)|| \leq |u(x) - \varphi (x)|,$ for all $x$ then $||u| - |\varphi|| \in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega) $. For $j>j_0$ we have for all x that  $|\varphi(x)| < j$, which implies $- |\varphi (x)| > -j$.

For all $x$ we have $\max(|u(x)| - |\varphi (x)| , 0) \geq \max(|u| - j, 0) \geq 0  \ (*)$.

Since $ |u| - |\varphi| \in  W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)  \rightarrow   (|u| - |\varphi|)^{+} \in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)  \ (**) $. From $(*)$ and (**) we have $(|u| - j)^{+} \in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega) .$

Comment: Could you specify paper mentioned in the answer, as well as the one that prompted the question?

Comment: ok =) . The paper is this  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5264v2.pdf and the question is related with   the beginning of page 13

Comment: The step from $u-\varphi$ to $|u-\varphi|$ is nontrivial, btw.

Comment: @NormalHuman The step from $u-\varphi\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ to $|u-\varphi|\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ follows from Stampacchia Theorem: The function $F(x)=|x|$ is Lipschitz continuous and $F(0)=0$ and therefore $F\,o\,(u-\varphi)\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. For me the step $||u(x)|-|\varphi(x)||\leq |u(x)-\varphi(x)|$ for all $x\Rightarrow ||u|-|\varphi||\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is not clear, as well as the last line.